# Only the First bootstrap3 modal (of many) is appearing on iOS devices?

Tags: ios, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, modalviewcontroller

Any reason why the first one of these modals (among even more) would appear on iOS devices?

..all of the modals appear on laptops

```
<div class="modal fade" id="contact" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contactModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <div class="logo"><img src="../public/img/logo.png" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default center-block" data-dismiss="modal"><strong>Press This</strong></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="item1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="item1Modal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="item1Modal">This</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">
        <p>
          Paragraph
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default center-block" data-dismiss="modal"><strong>Press This One!</strong></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this on my phone with a very simple page.  I added two buttons to open the modals...  looks like it's working on my phone (iphone 4S)

Is it possible that you have a javascript error somewhere that's only triggered on the phone?

Comment: @MatthewDoyle It works on android, though it still has yet to work on iOS.. Is there a way to test to see what the error might be on iOS?